# HTML email messed up in IE7 & Chrome

Tags: html-email

I coded this html [email](http://ryanspahn.com/sandy-mail/) and when I check it in Chrome and IE7 the photo of the women is broken up.  It looks fine in all other browsers.  In some email clients it is also broken up.

Anyone experience this before and or can offer a suggestion on how to fix?

thank you,
ryan

Comment: Did you have to break up the image of the woman.  Could you have used a single image and a <td rowspan="3">?

Answer (score 0):

Your image "sandy-portrait2.png" is stretching your upper table with beyond 600px wide to 638px wide.

Adjust your bottom table to match and you should be good. Also, you will need to recut or manually position "below-bottom-a-line.png" because it is only 600px wide and will not align correctly with the image in your upper table.

Also take note that since you are using `background` attribute on you `table`, Client such as Outlook 2007 will ignore this attribute and not display the background.